# Why does this code behave differently as a script than when entered on the console?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, empty, hook-modifier

I have a grid, (subdivided plane) open in edit mode.  If I run the attached script by pasting it into the python console, it creates an empty, adds a hook to the grid, and makes the empty the hook's object, set to a vertex as a parent.  Everything is fine and the empty and vertex are located in the same position.

But if I run the script with the run button, the vertex ends up displaced from the empty.

It is obvious that I am missing a step in my code that's being implicitly performed when I paste the code; probably something to do with state after the empty is created; but I can't figure out what I'm missing.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

```py
import bpy

collection = bpy.context.collection

def add_empty(name, type, size, collection):
    """ Add an empty to a collection """
    empty = bpy.data.objects.new(name, None)
    empty.empty_display_type = type
    empty.empty_display_size = size
    collection.objects.link(empty)
    return empty

object = bpy.context.active_object
empty = add_empty("HUH", "SPHERE", 0.1, collection)
vert = object.data.vertices[30]
empty.location=object.matrix_world @ vert.co
hook = object.modifiers.new(name="huh", type="HOOK")
hook.object = empty
hook.vertex_indices_set([vert.index])
```

blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the solution is to add

```py
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

after modifying `empty.location`, resulting in

```py
import bpy

collection = bpy.data.collections["Collection"]
object = bpy.context.active_object
empty = bpy.data.objects.new("Huh", None)
empty.empty_display_type = "SPHERE"
empty.empty_display_size = .1
collection.objects.link(empty)
vert = object.data.vertices[30]
empty.location=object.matrix_world @ vert.co
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
hook = object.modifiers.new(name="huh", type="HOOK")
hook.object = empty
hook.vertex_indices_set([vert.index])
```

The reason the code worked from the console is that each executed statement was resulting in the view layer being updated.

Comment: that's interesting! ;) nice catch